# No wi-fi icon/ option in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 the wifi icon and option just disappeared. I have tried to reboot it and searching the settings for it, but it does not let me connect to a wifi connection in any way. The only way to connect to the internet is with a wired connection. So how can I fix this and is this a bug or something that has to do with the version? I installed it on a Dell Inspiron 910 mini netbook.

Comment: Oops accidentally posted an answer. Run this in a terminal and let me know what it says: ps -A | grep nm-applet

Comment: Also, are you using the Unity desktop environment?

Comment: ummm.....quick questions, wheres the terminal and whats the Unity desktop environment?

Comment: yea sorry im kinda new to this

Comment: Does your desktop look like this? http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-zJmOyBP3IHc/UzPwmAd0G0I/AAAAAAAAR9w/UCyYogZDJNI/s1600/ubuntu14.04-unity.png

Comment: And don't worry about it. We all start somewhere.

Comment: yea it looks pretty much the same

Comment: Ok. You're using Unity. Click on the ubuntu icon in the upper left corner and type terminal. Hit enter afterwards.

Comment: ok found terminal, whats next?

Comment: type `ps -A | grep nm-applet` and hit enter

Comment: ok...after i entered it 1755 ?        00:00:00: nm-applet came out

Answer (score 16):

First you have to stop network manager from background:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

Remove file on `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state` path:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
```

Start network manager back:

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

[Source](http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/08/how-to-fix-missing-not-showing-network.html)

Comment: I was heading this way lol. This should work. If not, he might be missing a driver for his wireless card.

Comment: @SamuelCavazos Sorry i post it first, i know this ways from upubuntu. lol

Comment: It's not a problem at all. Excellent answer.

Comment: ok... i stopped the network manager and put in the sudo password but when i tried to put the  Remove file on command it says access denied?

Comment: please add output of your access denied

Comment: it says output is currently not installed, i typed the command it gave me to install it but it could not locate it

Comment: i mean what error you got on terminal when enter sudo password

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue. http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do

Comment: For newer versions of ubuntu using systemd rather than upstart, the commands to start and stop a the network manager service are `systemctl stop network-manager` and `systemctl start network-manager`. (Note that `systemctl` does not need to be run with `sudo`, as it will prompt you for sudo access itself.)

Answer (score 10):

I was facing this very same issue. Please note that wireless was working fine all this time, its just the missing icon.

Here is what worked for me. Unity -> Startup Applications - and check "Indicator Application" (if its not already checked.) Next install following two packages: `indicator-applet` and `indicator-network`.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet indicator-network
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit on Dell Inspiron 1564.

Comment: Thanks! Can't imagine why they thought it was a good idea to remove the icons.

Comment: @Jake I think it's kind of a bug, not by-design.