# System tray not being displayed correctly Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit

Tags: system-tray, tox

I have Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit and I have a Tox client installed. When I minimize the client to the system tray the icon isn't displayed in the correct place. Here is a screen-shot to help describe more.(The incorrectly displayed icon is located at the top left)[image]

Any solutions? 
Thanks & Regards
Isaac Cilia Attard

Comment: at what moment is the client started? on log in by any chance?

Comment: The client is started manually by launching the application

Comment: is the system tray icon started earlier?

Comment: Is the icon actually managed by the System Tray or by the application itself?

Comment: What I mean is, could it be connected to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/562259/dropbox-icon-in-the-wrong-place/562376#562376. So my next question is: would closing the application + systray icon / reopening it fix it (temporarily)?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes that problem is like mine, though I have tried to use the solution but I have not found the autostart folder in my .config folder. What could I do alternatively?

Comment: If you open Dash > Startup applications, is your application listed?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt
```

Comment: I already have it installed.