# Permanent Solution to disable touch pad while typing on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

The cursor keeps jumping on my Ubuntu 16.04. The solution described in ["Disable Touchpad while typing option" gone in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762189/disable-touchpad-while-typing-option-gone-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts?rq=1) requires giving the syndaemon command. This works for me but I have to keep giving this command everytime I start my system ( Dell Inspiron 25, 7000 series). Is there any permanent solution to do this (any check box I can tick somewhere ??)

Comment: Hi Ubkash, it can be solved adding a command to startup applications, but with a small break to prevent overruling by local procedures. It is a dupe, will find in a minute...

Comment: ...or you could try the answer by Pilot? Please mention if it works.

Comment: See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/568090/syndaemon-wont-start-as-startup-application/568307#568307

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by installing `libinput`. It has mush better palm detection and disable while typing algorithm.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt install xerver-xorg-input-libinput
```

Then run

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf
```

and add

```
Option "Tapping" "true"
```

to the touchpad section.

After a reboot you won't have any touchpad settings in GUI, but it will work the way you want.

Comment: @sudodus There is no need to add `universe` it is in the default Ubuntu.

Comment: @sudodus Please stop editing my answer. You can always write your own.

Comment: At least in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS *live*, which I am running to test your good answer, it is necessary to add `universe`. I think it means that it is also necessary in Ubuntu *persistent live*. Otherwise `libinput` is not found. (I only wanted to help, but I will try to remember to stay away from your answers.)

Comment: Live is a different story.

Answer (score 2):

Install `touchpad-indicator`. It'll put an icon in your top panel, and is fully configurable via a GUI. It actually uses syndaemon under the skin.

For more information, see http://tipsonubuntu.com/2014/05/26/install-touchpad-indicator-ubuntu-14-04/. From that site:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

The software can also be found at https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/atareao and https://launchpad.net/touchpad-indicator.

Answer (score 1):

[`syndaemon(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/syndaemon.1.html) does not have a configuration file or way to autostart itself.  You can treat it like any normal program or script which needs to be autostarted.

The simplest method is to modify your [`crontab(5)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/crontab.5.html) and use the `@reboot` alias.

Or you can follow the [more graphical way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login).

Reference:

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/syndaemon.1.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/crontab.5.html
- http://www.computercorrect.com/2012/operating-systems/linux/xubuntu/configure-disable-touchpad-while-typing-delay/
- [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me to do it via the graphical user interface.

1. Click on the icon with the cog wheel and wrench
2. In the System Settings window, Click on 'Mouse and Touchpad'
3. In the Mouse and Touchpad window, click on the switch icon at the right side. You will see that it switches from 'ON' to 'OFF'
4. That's it. You can close the window, and Ubuntu will remember the setting (unless it is a live-only system that cannot remember anything).

---

If you don't want the touchpad completely off, you can turn off only 'tap to click' and 'two finger scrolling' and leave the switch on the right side 'ON'.

---

If you are not satisfied with the suggestions above, you can put the command that works for you (with `syndaemon`) into 'autostart' according to the following link,

[How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Comment: This seems to be explaining how to disable the touchpad *entirely*. Does "Mouse and Touchpad" in System Settings also include an option to disable the touchpad *just while text is being entered*, but have it otherwise enabled? Judging from the OP's question title, linked question, and use of `syndaemon`, that's what the OP is looking for. (I'm not asking this rhetorically; I don't have any Unity or GNOME based Ubuntu systems set up currently -- I mainly use Lubuntu -- and I don't know if there's a setting for this in "Mouse and Touchpad." If so, you might want to add details about it.)

Comment: I booted a live Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, and performed the actions, that I recommend. There is no option, that does exactly what the OP wants. It would be an option to recommend to put the command, that obviously works, into 'autostart', but it is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

This can work around as part of the solution: while read line; do if [[ $line == *"Touchpad"* ]]; then tid="$(echo $line | cut -d'=' -f2 |cut -c1-2)"; xinput set-prop $tid "Device Enabled" 0; fi; done < <(xinput list