# dropbox issue on Xenial

Tags: updates, xubuntu, dropbox

I installed Xubuntu 16.04 one month ago. Since about one week Dropbox asks for an updated to the last version and now it has stopped syncing. I already has the latest version installed (also checked on the dropbox website). Any hint?
Thank you

[image: dropbox update]

Comment: Just to clarify - what Dropbox version is the latest according to your research?

Comment: 2015.10.28 (amd64)

Comment: Alright, that is what i am using on 16.04 as well (without issues).

Comment: The dropbox documentation/help regarding this issue: https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/6251

Comment: Following the suggestion in the dropbox documentation did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

Quit Dropbox from running.

```
dropbox stop
```

Delete `~/.dropbox-dist`.

```
rm -r ~/.dropbox-dist
```

Now just run the two commands under the "Dropbox Headless Install via command line" option here https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx. Select whether you have a 64 or 32 bit machine.

This will preserve the Dropbox cache so it won't re-sync everything. If this does not work, you may want to consider a complete uninstall and purge, and reinstall of the Dropbox program. (There is of course no need to remove the files in your Dropbox folder as all of this pertains to the program.)

Comment: At least now the command-line version works. Thank you.

Comment: Do you not have file browser integration? I wrote a script that integrates Dropbox into Thunar. It would work with other file browsers too. I'd be glad to post if interested.

Comment: I used to have the thunar-dropbox-plugin but it does not work with the version I installed to fix my problem. I can try your script if you post it.

Comment: @Giangiacomo I am using 14.04 with Xfce 4.12 PPA, and thunar-dropbox-plugin broke for me too. I reported it, but fortunately I also discovered that Dropbox expanded its CLI options to include share links etc. Since Thunar integration is a different topic, I recommend posting a different question on askubuntu. Be sure to mention that thunar-dropbox-plugin is not working so folks won't give that as a solution. Then I'll post an answer with my script to that question. If my answer here solved your issue, please be sure to click the green check below the arrows and/or upvote. Thanks

Comment: @Giangiacomo Never mind. I posted the question and answer here. Please let me know if you have any questions with it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/777878/how-to-integrate-dropbox-in-thunar

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fix based on the previous answers that worked fine for me:

1) `dropbox stop`

2) `rm -r ~/.dropbox-dist`

3a) (for a 64 bit machine) `cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -`

3b) (for a 32 bit machine) `cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -`

4) `start dropbox`

That worked except for the missing dropbox icon on the panel. To fix it I followed the advices from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732816/xubuntu-dropbox-icon-fail).