# How to Integrate Dropbox in Thunar?

Tags: bash, scripts, xfce, dropbox, thunar

How can I integrate Dropbox into Thunar? I am using Xubuntu 14.04 with Xfce 4.12 installed via PPA, and `thunar-dropbox-plugin` has been broken. I have also heard that it is not working on Xubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately, Dropbox recently expanded [their CLI capabilities](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/9192) to include sharelinks etc. To integrate Dropbox into Thunar do the following:

#### Initial Setup

Create a `~/bin` directory in your home folder if not already created. Download the [Dropbox python script](https://linux.dropbox.com/packages/dropbox.py). Rename it as just `dropbox`. (The extension is not needed.) Make it executable `chmod +x ~/bin/dropbox`.

If the `~/bin` directory is not already added to your `$PATH` (i.e. tab completion doesn't work for the script, etc.), you would add the following to `~/.profile`. Then log out and in again.

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Install `xsel` by pasting `sudo apt-get install xsel` in terminal. This program gives clipboard functionality to the below script.

Save the following script to a plain text file, save it in `~/bin`, and make it executable. Mine is named `dropbox-online`. Change `icon_path="/full/path/to/dropbox-icon.png"` to the path to your [Dropbox icon](https://www.google.com/search?q=dropbox%20icon&newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&hs=uZg&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9_PiToPjMAhXCSSYKHW0sCysQsAQIHA&biw=1920&bih=970).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Name:     Dropbox Thunar Integration
# Author:   jbrock
# Dependencies: xsel (in Ubuntu repository), Dropbox python script https://linux.dropbox.com/packages/dropbox.py
# Installation: http://askubuntu.com/questions/777878/how-to-integrate-dropbox-in-thunar

notify_time=5000
icon_path="/full/path/to/dropbox-icon.png"
internet_status=$(ping -c 1 dropbox.com > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)
dropbox_status=$(dropbox status)

web_directory () {
    prepend_path="https://www.dropbox.com/home/"
    append_path=$(pwd | cut -d "/" -f5-)
    xdg-open "$prepend_path$append_path"
}

gui_notify () {
    notify-send -t "$notify_time" -i "$icon_path" "$1"
}

# Check: 1. internet connection; 2. if Dropbox is running; 3. if in Dropbox or Public folder.

if [ "$internet_status" != 0 ]; then
    gui_notify "There is an internet connectivity issue."
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$dropbox_status" = "Dropbox isn't running!" ]; then
    gui_notify "Dropbox isn't running."
    exit 1
fi

if [[ "$2" != *Dropbox* ]]; then
    gui_notify "You are not in Dropbox."
    exit 1
fi  

if [[ "$1" = -p && "$2" != *Dropbox\/Public* ]]; then
    gui_notify "You are not in the Dropbox/Public folder."
    exit 1
fi

case "$1" in
    -p )
        dropbox puburl "$2" | tr -d '\n' | xsel -ib && gui_notify "Public Link Copied" ;;
    -s )
        dropbox sharelink "$2" | tr -d '\n' | xsel -ib && gui_notify "Share Link Copied" ;;
    -d )
        web_directory ;;
esac
```

#### Thunar Integration

To integrate into Thunar. Go to Edit > Configure custom actions. Click the plus to add a custom action. Set up the following three custom actions:

[image: Add Share Link]

[image: Add Public Link]

[image: Add Directory Online]

Remember too that you can add your own icon to appear on the Thunar context menu items.

For each of these you'll want to do the following on the second tab given that you want to be able to share any type of file or directory.

[image: Appearance Conditions]

The only downside is that the three Dropbox menu items appear globally in Thunar, not only in Dropbox. However, the script tells you if you are accidentally outside of Dropbox.

**Update:** The command `dropbox puburl` no longer works. Dropbox no longer has the Public folder for free accounts and discontinues it for paid ones on September 1, 2017.

Comment: you need to add ~/bin into $PATH, right?

Comment: I added in these instructions above. I am now on Debian, but the last time I created a `~/bin` in Xubuntu it was already added to `$PATH`.

Comment: curious - I didn't have to add it and the autocomplete still works (xubuntu 16.04)

Comment: @jena I figured Xubuntu would have that already set up for you as it was when I used to use it. In Debian I had to set that up in `~/.profile` as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

[This should be a comment, apologies but I have not the reputation yet.]

@jbrock

Thank you! I have found that I need to write for example for the Share Link:

```
dropbox-online -s %n
```

rather than %f, and it seems to be smart enough to work out where in the file system it is.

Also, I'm running two dropbox processes; for me I overwhelmingly need it for just one of them, so I have set the HOME env var in lines toward the end of your script:

```
HOME=/home/mike/.dropbox-work dropbox sharelink "$2" | tr -d '\n' | xsel -ib && gui_notify "Share Link Copied" ;;
```

Works well.