# Weird icon on my icon tray

Tags: xubuntu, icons, dropbox

Does anyone know what this is? It started to show up after I installed Dropbox I think, and nothing is showing up when I tried to click it. It doesn't change the behavior of my desktop though and the Dropbox folder works fine too. I just want to know what this weird icon is. Thank you!

[image: The leftmost icon has a 'cancel' display]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xubuntu Dropbox Icon Fail](http://askubuntu.com/questions/732816/xubuntu-dropbox-icon-fail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is **dropbox** doing it's recent failing thing. Run this:

`dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start`

I had the same problem. It's more of a workaround, but it works. It helps to create a custom command to just run that real quick. Create an alias in `/home/<user>/.bashrc`:

alias db='dropbox stop && dbus dropbox-start`

Or, I wrote a script with that in it, then did

`sudo install db.sh /path/to/db.sh/commandname`

where `commandname` runs `db.sh` from the terminal.

Comment: Thank you!  That was driving me crazy as mine was doing that too!  =)

Comment: Sure thing. Yeah, I don't know what exactly is going on with it yet, but there are no options shown on right click, right? Just a blank menu... but this works for now, for me, and good, for you too! Cheers!

Comment: That is exactly what mine was doing too.  No options when right clicking at all.  But I needed my dropbox for my Plex Media Server database backup I run, and it wasn't backing up with it failing.  So, this works.  =)

Comment: Hey this was on another question, looks like a permanent workaround to hide this behavior: **The command line command works great but only works for that session. To make the fix permanent, one should, after running this command, go to the Dropbox indicator > Preferences... > uncheck Start Dropbox on system startup. Then add dbus-launch dropbox start to Session and Startup > Application Autostart. This works perfectly for me on Xubuntu 16.04 LTS. – Ads20000**

Comment: I guess that makes this question a duplicate sort of, but here's that thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/dropbox-icon-is-not-working-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64