# Xubuntu indicator plugin icons blank

Tags: xubuntu, icons, indicator, dropbox, viber

My Dropbox and Viber icons are blank and I don't really know how to fix this. I tried adding the icons to the theme, but nothing happens. I'm running Xubuntu 16.10, but it has been an issue since I installed 16.04.

[image]

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libappindicator1`, log out and log in again.

Comment: For Dropbox this solution works. http://askubuntu.com/a/744500/573457

Comment: It doesn't work for me. 
dropbox stop && DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="" dropbox start
used to work as a temporary solution, but even that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Also:
libappindicator1 is already the newest version (12.10.1+16.10.20160905-0ubuntu1).

Answer (score 1):

Edited

```
mousepad /home/YOUR_NAME/.local/share/applications/viber.desktop
```

to:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Viber
Comment=Viber VoIP and messenger
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/viber.png
Exec=dbus-launch /opt/viber/Viber
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Application;Network;
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
```

to fix the Viber icon.