# DropBox tray icon/indicator on XUbuntu not working

Tags: xubuntu, icons, dropbox, notification-area

DropBox icon replaced by a crossed red circle, but also no menu linked to it, it's a quite annoying problem.

I am searching for a solution for this DropBox icon on XUbuntu for many months/years. None of the tested solutions worked.

I had the problem on several machines, with several versions of XUbuntu.

Useful linked subjects (but solutions didn't worked for me):

[Xubuntu Dropbox icon fail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732816/xubuntu-dropbox-icon-fail)

[How to fix non working Dropbox icon on Xubuntu 14.04 LTS 64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/how-to-fix-non-working-dropbox-icon-on-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fact, this solution, found in many places, was nearly the good one, but didn't worked for me... till I have the idea to make a very small modification : put something inside the quote, like "DROPBOX" ! (in fact, any text could certainly be ok).

1. open `/usr/bin/dropbox` in an text editor (using `sudo`). For example on XUbuntu :

   `sudo mousepad /usr/bin/dropbox`
2. after the line `import os`, add this line :

   `os.environ['DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'] = "DROPBOX"`
3. save, then restart DropBox, or log out/in.

As far as I understand it, this prevents DropBox to find the system notification area, where it doesn't work, and forces it to directly use the main panel, where it works.