# Where to get libpulse-mainloop-glib >= 0.9.19?

Tags: package-management, compiling, libraries

I'm trying to compile [Xfce Pulse Audio Plugin](https://bluesabre.org/2017/10/01/development-release-xfce-pulseaudio-plugin-0-3-1/). But have problem with ./configure:

```
checking for libpulse-mainloop-glib >= 0.9.19... not found
*** The required package libpulse-mainloop-glib was not found on your system.
*** Please install libpulse-mainloop-glib (atleast version 0.9.19) or adjust
*** the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
*** installed the package in a nonstandard prefix so that
*** pkg-config is able to find it.
```

I can't find **libpulse-mainloop-glib**, I only can find **libpulse-mainloop-glib0** (with **0** at the end).

Comment: Have you tried using `libpulse-mainloop-glib0`?  It's possible that's the package name but it actually provides that specific library.

Comment: Issues like this are almost always because you didn't install the relevant **development** package - in this case, that would be `libpulse-dev` AFAIK (which includes development libraries and headers for `libpulse`, `libpulse-simple` **and** `libpulse-mainloop-glib`0. See for example [File list of package libpulse-dev in bionic of architecture amd64](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libpulse-dev/filelist)

Comment: @Thomas Ward I have it, still was needing what is asks.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, now it asks for `libxfce4util-1.0`.
How can I see all what .configure needs and where to get it ?

Comment: @RS try `apt-cache search dev | grep libxfce4util`