# Can't connect to Wi-Fi..Wi-Fi option is missing from both system setting and dropdown bar

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, realtek-wireless

I cannot connect to Wi-Fi.The Wi-fi tab is missing from the dropdown menu and also there is no mention of wireless in the networking tab of System Setting.I can only connect through Ethernet..I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in a hp laptop with realtek wireless card.
The output of

> sudo lshw -c network

was

```
*-network

   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 08
   serial: 38:63:bb:a6:46:14
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:48 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c6004000-c6004fff memory:c6000000-c6003fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 3
   logical name: enxfcde56ff0106
   serial: fc:de:56:ff:01:06
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.1.102 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Also tried a wireless info script

> ```
>      wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
>  chmod +x wireless-info &&
>  ./wireless-info
> ```

gave out the script

> 

```
> 
> ########## wireless info START ##########
> 
> Report from: 06 Jul 2017 10:59 IST +0530
> 
> Booted last: 06 Jul 2017 00:00 IST +0530
> 
> Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000
> 
> ##### release ###########################
> 
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Release: 16.04
> Codename: xenial
> 
> ##### kernel ############################
> 
> Linux 4.8.0-53-generic #56~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 16 01:18:56 UTC
> 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> 
> Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7
> 
> ##### desktop ###########################
> 
> Ubuntu
> 
> ##### lspci #############################
> 
> 08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
> RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136]
> (rev 08)  DeviceName: Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller   Subsystem:
> Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet
> controller [103c:2296]
> 
> ##### lsusb #############################
> 
> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Bus 001
> Device 003: ID 0bda:b001 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.  Bus 001 Device
> 002: ID 064e:c344 Suyin Corp.  Bus 001 Device 010: ID 05c6:f00e
> Qualcomm, Inc.  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0
> root hub
> 
> ##### PCMCIA card info ##################
> 
> ##### rfkill ############################
> 
> 0: hci0: Bluetooth    Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no
> 
> ##### lsmod #############################
> 
> hp_wmi                 16384  0 sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
> mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau wmi                    16384 
> 3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,hp_wmi
> 
> ##### interfaces ########################
> 
> auto lo iface lo inet loopback
> 
> ##### ifconfig ##########################
> 
> eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>  
>           UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>           RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
> 
> enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enx<IF from
> MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>  
>           inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>           inet6 addr: fe80::890f:f4f4:5a72:5e4a/64 Scope:Link
>           inet6 addr: 2405:204:d482:706c:b13e:6d29:eac:a886/64 Scope:Global
>           inet6 addr: 2405:204:d482:706c:58ae:92de:cd4:3538/64 Scope:Global
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:6022 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:5721 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>           RX bytes:3767364 (3.7 MB)  TX bytes:976879 (976.8 KB)
> 
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
>           inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>           RX packets:3896 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:3896 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
>           RX bytes:308502 (308.5 KB)  TX bytes:308502 (308.5 KB)
> 
> ##### iwconfig ##########################
> 
> eno1      no wireless extensions.
> 
> lo        no wireless extensions.
> 
> enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no wireless extensions.
> 
> ##### route #############################
> 
> Kernel IP routing table Destination     Gateway         Genmask       
> Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
> 0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
> 169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
> 192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
> 
> ##### resolv.conf #######################
> 
> nameserver 127.0.1.1
> 
> ##### network managers ##################
> 
> Installed:
> 
>   NetworkManager
> 
> Running:
> 
> root      3745     1  0 10:53 ?        00:00:00
> /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
> 
> ##### NetworkManager info ###############
> 
> GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
> GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet GENERAL.NM-TYPE:     
> NMDeviceEthernet GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Qualcomm
> GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Mobile Router GENERAL.DRIVER: 
> rndis_host GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
> GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device GENERAL.HWADDR:  
> <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]> GENERAL.MTU:                     
> 1500 GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
> GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
> GENERAL.UDI:                           
> /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/net/enx<IF from
> MAC [IF2]> GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC
> [IF2]> GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no GENERAL.NM-MANAGED: 
> yes GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
> GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING: 
> no GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   -- GENERAL.CONNECTION:     
> Wired connection 2 GENERAL.CON-UUID:                      
> c75a3a87-c6f9-30ff-9e62-c9b94340d834 GENERAL.CON-PATH:                
> /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1 GENERAL.METERED:   
> no (guessed) CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
> CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
> CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:  
> on CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS:
> /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{11}
> CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:  
> c75a3a87-c6f9-30ff-9e62-c9b94340d834 | Wired connection 2
> IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.102/24 IP4.GATEWAY: 
> 192.168.1.1 IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000 IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1 DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
> DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
> DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                       
> requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[6]:        
> requested_broadcast_address = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                      
> requested_netbios_scope = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                       
> requested_wpad = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server
> = 0.0.0.0 DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1499347549 DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
> DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
> DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 28800
> DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
> DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.102
> DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
> DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers
> = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1 DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address =
> 192.168.1.255 DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                      
> requested_netbios_name_servers = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                  
> domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.1 DHCP4.OPTION[23]:       
> requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[24]:            
> subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0 DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                      
> network_number = 192.168.1.0 DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                      
> requested_host_name = 1 DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                      
> dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1 IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                  
> 2405:204:d482:706c:58ae:92de:cd4:3538/64 IP6.ADDRESS[2]:              
> 2405:204:d482:706c:b13e:6d29:eac:a886/64 IP6.ADDRESS[3]:              
> fe80::890f:f4f4:5a72:5e4a/64 IP6.GATEWAY:                           
> fe80::e812:5bff:fedc:76cc
> 
> GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1 GENERAL.TYPE:            
> ethernet GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
> GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co.,
> Ltd. GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express
> Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller GENERAL.DRIVER:                      
> r8169 GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
> GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13
> GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
> GENERAL.MTU:                            1500 GENERAL.STATE:           
> 20 (unavailable) GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is
> now managed) GENERAL.UDI:                           
> /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:08:00.0/net/eno1
> GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                        GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:         
> no GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:   
> yes GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
> GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:      
> -- GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     -- GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       -- GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       -- GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
> CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
> CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:  
> off CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 
> 
> ##### NetworkManager.state ##############
> 
> [main] NetworkingEnabled=true WirelessEnabled=true WWANEnabled=true
> 
> ##### NetworkManager.conf ###############
> 
> [main] plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono dns=dnsmasq
> 
> [ifupdown] managed=false
> 
> ##### NetworkManager profiles ###########
> 
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/umi 1]] (600 root)
> [connection] id=umi 1 | type=wifi | permissions=user:umi:; [wifi]
> mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=umi [ipv4]
> method=auto [ipv6] method=auto
> 
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/JioFi2_E6BB27]] (600 root)
> [connection] id=JioFi2_E6BB27 | type=wifi | permissions=user:umi:;
> [wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= |
> ssid=JioFi2_E6BB27 [ipv4] method=auto [ipv6] method=auto
> 
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MIFRAH_Jio]] (600 root)
> [connection] id=MIFRAH_Jio | type=wifi | permissions=user:umi:; [wifi]
> mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=MIFRAH_Jio
> [ipv4] method=auto [ipv6] method=auto
> 
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MBLAZE-DF800i-5979]] (600
> root) [connection] id=MBLAZE-DF800i-5979 | type=wifi |
> permissions=user:umi:; [wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> |
> mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=MBLAZE-DF800i-5979 [ipv4] method=auto
> [ipv6] method=auto
> 
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/JioFi3_6A369D]] (600 root)
> [connection] id=JioFi3_6A369D | type=wifi | permissions=user:umi:;
> [wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= |
> ssid=JioFi3_6A369D [ipv4] method=auto [ipv6] method=auto
> 
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Lenovo A7000-a]] (600 root)
> [connection] id=Lenovo A7000-a | type=wifi | permissions=user:umi:;
> [wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= |
> ssid=Lenovo A7000-a [ipv4] method=auto [ipv6] method=auto
> 
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/umi]] (600 root) [connection]
> id=umi | type=wifi | permissions=user:umi:; [wifi] mac-address=<MAC
> address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=umi [ipv4] method=auto [ipv6]
> method=auto
> 
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/tARgarYeN]] (600 root)
> [connection] id=tARgarYeN | type=wifi | permissions=user:umi:; [wifi]
> mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=tARgarYeN
> [ipv4] method=auto [ipv6] method=auto
> 
> ##### iw reg get ########################
> 
> Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)
> 
> country 00: DFS-UNSET     (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)  (2457 -
> 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN  (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20),
> (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN  (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A),
> PASSIVE-SCAN  (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
>   (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN     (5735 - 5835
> @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN   (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0),
> (N/A)
> 
> ##### iwlist channels ###################
> 
> eno1      no frequency information.
> 
> lo        no frequency information.
> 
> enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no frequency information.
> 
> ##### iwlist scan #######################
> 
> eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.
> 
> lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
> 
> enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.
> 
> ##### module infos ######################
> 
> ##### module parameters #################
> 
> ##### /etc/modules ######################
> 
> ##### modprobe options ##################
> 
> [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf] blacklist ath_pci
> 
> [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf] blacklist evbug blacklist usbmouse
> blacklist usbkbd blacklist eepro100 blacklist de4x5 blacklist eth1394
> blacklist snd_intel8x0m blacklist snd_aw2 blacklist i2c_i801 blacklist
> prism54
> 
> blacklist bcm43xx blacklist garmin_gps blacklist asus_acpi blacklist
> snd_pcsp blacklist pcspkr blacklist amd76x_edac
> 
> [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf] alias net-pf-3 off alias
> net-pf-6 off alias net-pf-9 off alias net-pf-11 off alias net-pf-12
> off alias net-pf-19 off alias net-pf-21 off alias net-pf-36 off
> 
> [/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf] blacklist microcode
> 
> [/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf] remove iwlwifi \ (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o
> -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \ && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
> 
> [/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf] softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en
> 
> ##### rc.local ##########################
> 
> exit 0
> 
> ##### pm-utils ##########################
> 
> ##### udev rules ########################
> 
> ##### dmesg #############################
> 
> [  695.446408] rndis_host 1-2:1.0 eth0: register 'rndis_host' at
> usb-0000:00:14.0-2, RNDIS device, <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
> [  695.490758] rndis_host 1-2:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: renamed from
> eth0 [  695.512718] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>:
> link is not ready
> 
> ########## wireless info END ############
```

Tried this solution https://askubuntu.com/a/475579/708177 stil no use..
Anyone please help..I'm new to Linux..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I run Ubuntu 16.04 on a Compaq CQ62 with RTL8191SEvA Wireless LAN Controller and like you a RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller.  When my WiFi hangs up I remove/re-insert kernel modules with the following commands as root.  These commands are not persistent across reboots so if they make matters worse simply reboot.  Use `lsmod | more` to get an idea of what modules are loaded in your kernel and to see if rtlwifi is present.

```
netstat -rn    # Note the gateway address for destination 0.0.0.0
systemctl stop network-manager
ip link set wlo1 down
ip link set lo down
modprobe -r rtl8192se
modprobe -r rtl_pci
modprobe -r rtlwifi
modprobe -r mac80211
modprobe -r cfg80211
# Then reinsert the modules and rebuild the network interfaces
modprobe cfg80211
modprobe mac80211
modprobe rtlwifi
modprobe rtl_pci
modprobe rtl8192se
ip link set lo up
ip link set wlo1 up
systemctl start network-manager
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1    # but use your gateway address
ps -e | grep -q nm-applet || nm-applet &
```

Of course it's possible that your WiFi controller isn't supported by Linux.

Comment: <ip link set wlo1 down> shows 'cannot find device wlo1'

Comment: @Umi That's not surprising since it isn't listed by `lshw`. Look at the output of `lsmod` and see if the rtl entries are present.  Try adding them or just run all the commands above and see if that makes any difference.